# (phpmyadmin)(Mysql database) how can I limited the number of insert of specific key value?

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

For example, I have different courses. A course can be registered by multiple students, but a student (ID) can only register for 2 courses.

How can I limit the occurrences of a student (ID) to 2?

Like:

> course_student_table
>
> CourseID StudentID
>
> 0123        5432
>
> 0123        5434
>
> 0124        5432
>
> 0127        5432

In this case, how can I limit the numbers of entry of ID 5432?

Comment: Please share your the structure of your table(s).

Comment: You'd handle this at the application level, not the database level, via validation.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a "BEFORE INSERT" trigger to deny the insert, but most likely you want to handle this at the application level.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/trigger-syntax.html